# Layout not exporting

Tags: layouts

I am using QGIS 3.4 (Madeira).When attemptng to export my layout as jpeg or pdf, I get the message that the layout has been successfully exported, along with the path, but nothing shows up in the destination specified. 
I have tried adjusting the export resolution, the destination and restarted the program. (After each attempt the asterisk appears after the project title which shows that the project hasn't been saved.)

Any ideas?

Comment: What software are you using? What settings have you selected when trying to export?